# Cocos2dx 3.4 - manipulating user input

Tags: text, input, field, cocos2d-x

I am working on a breakout-type game using Cocos2dx.

I need to make a highscore table. After the game is finished, I'd like to display a page, where player types his username into text field.

I don't know how to add the user input into variable, so I can manipulate it later (mainly saving along with score to display it on the selected scene).

What is the simplest way of doing so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Approach One:**
If you just need to handle keyboard as `key-event`, It's as easy as these below lines of code:

```cpp
HelloWorld::init()
{ 
    ...
    auto keyboardListener = EventListenerKeyboard::create();
    keyboardListener->onKeyPressed = [](EventKeyboard::KeyCode keyCode, Event* event)
    {
        switch (keyCode)
        {
        case EventKeyboard::KeyCode::KEY_UP_ARROW:      /*Jump maybe*/  break;
        case EventKeyboard::KeyCode::KEY_DOWN_ARROW:    /*Crouch maybe*/    break;
        case EventKeyboard::KeyCode::KEY_RIGHT_ARROW:   /*Move Right maybe*/    break;
        case EventKeyboard::KeyCode::KEY_LEFT_ARROW:    /*Move Left maybe*/ break;
        }
    };
    _eventDispatcher->addEventListenerWithSceneGraphPriority(keyboardListener, this);
    ...
return true;
}
```

I think it's clear enough not to need any extra description.

**Approach Two:** if you need an `input box` that user/player can enter string with `keyboard` and you get what is entered, I recommend to use `TextField` which is available in cocos2d v3 ( and with some difficulty  in v2) and has a full functionality. You can create and initial one of them as:

```cpp
auto textField = cocos2d::ui::TextField::create("hint: enter here","Arial" , 30);
textField->setTextHorizontalAlignment(cocos2d::TextHAlignment::CENTER);
textField->setTextVerticalAlignment(cocos2d::TextVAlignment::CENTER);
textField->setColor(Color3B(100,100,100));
textField->setMaxLength(10);
textField->setMaxLengthEnabled(true);
textField->setTouchAreaEnabled(true);
textField->setTouchSize(Size(200,400));
textField->setPosition(...);
textField->addEventListener(CC_CALLBACK_2(HelloWorld::textFieldEvent, this));
this->addChild(textField, 10);
```

You can get entered data any time with `std::string enteredData= textField->getString();`

You can also do something when user entering text with two event as :

```cpp
void HelloWorld::textFieldEvent(Ref *pSender, cocos2d::ui::TextField::EventType type)
{
    switch (type)
    {
    case cocos2d::ui::TextField::EventType::ATTACH_WITH_IME:
    {
        textField->setColor(Color3B::BLACK);
        // or whatever elese
        break;
    }
    case cocos2d::ui::TextField::EventType::DETACH_WITH_IME:
    {
        textField->setColor(Color3B(100,100,100));
        // or whatever elese
        break;
    }
    }
}
```

Enjoy !

Comment: Sorry, I have one more issue. When i try to use `std::string enteredData = textField->getString()` in the program it crashes with Access Violation error. Do you know what could be the reason?